# About the classic definition of field

Tags: field-theory, definition

Taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20field%20is,many%20other%20areas%20of%20mathematics.)

"*This may be summarized by saying: a field has two operations, called addition and multiplication; it is an abelian group under addition with $0$ as the additive identity; the nonzero elements are an abelian group under multiplication with $1$ as the multiplicative identity; and multiplication distributes over addition*".

Someone recently pointed out that if we consider this definition then we would be excluding zero from the product, since we are only considering non-zero elements in the multiplicative group. I think this is not so, but I am not sure how to justify this.

Could you help me?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Multiplication by $0$ is still defined. However, the whole field is not a group with respect to this operation.

Comment: That multiplication by $0$ is defined is understood when they say that there is the multiplication operation (which handles any two elements of the field). The nonzero elements form a group under multiplication, but this doesn't mean that multiplication by $0$ is not defined.